# Can I apply for UK Visitor visa from the USA on a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, uk-visitor-visa

I am an Indian Citizen on a B1/B2 visa visiting my son in the US. After visiting my son, I want to travel to the UK on a visitor visa. Can I apply for the UK visitor visa from the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The UK does not require visitor visa applications to be made from your home country/country of residence. To apply for a UK visa in the USA you need to:

- apply online
- pay your fee
- book and attend your biometric appointment
- Attend an Application Support Centre (ASC)
- post your application

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa